# Динамическая перезагрузка скрипта библиотеки MathJax

Tags: mathjax, jquery, tex, php, javascript

Добрый день, есть вопрос как отобразить динамически подруженую формулу TEX, через сию библиотеку  [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)

Нашел документацию по этому поводу и даже динамически отобразил нужную мне формулу, но только один раз. При повторной вставке библиотека не срабатывает. Не могу понять почему, наверное я что-то не уловил в документации.

вот [описание](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/dynamic.html) метода по динамическому подключению.

Моя попытка

```
<div id="test">test</div>
<button onclick="run()">TEST</button>

<script>
    function run() {    
        var url = 'response.php';
        var posting = $.post( url );            
        
        posting.done(function( data ) {
            $( "#test" ).html(data);
            loadMathJax();    
        });

    }

    function loadMathJax() {    
        // Remove previous scripts
        var mathJaxScript = document.getElementById('mathJaxSource'); 

        if ( !is_empty(mathJaxScript) ) {
            Element.prototype.remove = function() {
                this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
            }
            NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
                for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
                        this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            mathJaxScript.remove();  

        }

   // Загрузка библиотеки
        (function () {

            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.id = "mathJaxSource";
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src  = "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js";

            var config = 'MathJax.Hub.Config({' +
                           'extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],' +
                           'jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"]' +
                         '});' +
                         'MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();';

            if (window.opera) {script.innerHTML = config}
                         else {script.text = config}
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
          })()
    }

</script>
```

Страницу перезагружать нельзя.

Если кто-то сталкивался, ткните носом пжл. У меня подозрения, что я намудрил со вставкой-удалением скрипта, вернее со временем его загрузки

с сервера я просто форумулу tex  печатаю в echo.

Спасибо за любой совет.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:**

После динамического добавления скрипта создается и добавляется в документ еще несколько скриптов, мне надо как-то отловить их и удалить не затронув мои скрипты.

Comment: какой ответ приходит из 'response.php'; ?

Comment: просто фoмула tex, echo "\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\)";